# which database for cloud web app

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle11g, cloud

I am making a cloud storage web app. Which database should i use to store my files( files include the folders which users should be able to add) and other media files.I am confused between oracle database and Sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both databases are fine, but if your are choosing cloud storage or any services such amazon cloud etc then go for sqlserver database